# Politica CORS no me deja hacer POST

Tags: php, post, axios, cors

Estoy haciendo un proyecto con Svelte, axios y PHP como backend.
Y por ende a PHP le puse estos headers

```php
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5000");   
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");                              
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");    
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");
```

Cuando hago request a unos datos mediante get todo funciona y php me regresa un json al cual manejo en el front end.
El problema es cuando hago un post, que al final solo me regresa un numero(sin formato json ni nada) me sale el siguiente error

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/Notas/addBox' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Funcion front-end get:

```js
      function getBoxes() {
          boxes = undefined;
          axios.get("http://localhost/Notas/getBoxes")
              .then(resp => { boxes = resp.data; console.log(boxes) });
      }; getBoxes();
```

Funcion front-end post:

```js
    function createBox() {
        let name = val.value;
        if(name.length > 0) {
            axios({
                url: "http://localhost/Notas/addBox", 
                method: "post",
                data: { name }
            })
                .then(resp => {
                    dispatcher("added", {
                        id: resp.data,
                        name,
                        creation: Date.now().toString()
                    });
                    toggle();
                }); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Podrías probar con  `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` siempre que no sea un POST que necesite enviar credenciales

Comment: @ffflabs ya probé con Origin; *
Y no, no envio credenciales, solo envio un string del nombre de la caja que se creará